# How to use replace in android room database sql?

Tags: android, android-room

```
    @Query("update bookmarks set bookmarks_path= replace(bookmarks_path,:oldPath,:newPath) where bookmarks_path like :oldPath || '%'")
    fun updateBookmarksPath(oldPath: String, newPath: String): Completable
```

**I am using the room database and this is my code**

**I found that the format of this code is not correct when running, android studio prompts me: expression expected, got'replace'**

**like this**

[image]

**I want to achieve the effect like this**

----path------------------path

/root/1/1--------------/stack/1/1

/root/name/1------/stack/name/1

/root/cls/1-----------/stack/cls/1

/root/go/1-----------/stack/go/1

/root/js/1------------/stack/js/1

please

Comment: I don't understand why You want do to string operations in Your sql statement. I wouldn't to that. In fact room doesn't support all SQL statements. Probably `replace` is one of them.

Comment: If I modify it in the code, I need to search for all the data that matches, and modify them, and modify them again in the database, using this method can directly modify them, this SQL can be executed, although the error still exists, I think this may be SQL syntax correction, but does not affect code execution

Comment: as Bob Snyder mentioned, it works with backticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`REPLACE` is both an [SQLite keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) and, in the case of your intended use, the name of a string function: [replace()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) .
The Room annotation processor appears to be rejecting your query string because it is treating `replace` as keyword instead of function name. Maybe a bug?

Some quick experiments indicate that a possible solution is to surround `replace` in backticks to mark is as a name (see keyword link above).  Please give it a try:

```
@Query("update bookmarks set bookmarks_path= `replace`(bookmarks_path,:oldPath,:newPath) where bookmarks_path like :oldPath || '%'")
fun updateBookmarksPath(oldPath: String, newPath: String): Completable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,When using this method, the error is: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error), I try to run without modifying anything, it can run successfully, and can To achieve the effect I want, although he prompts an error, it can still be built

Comment: Please edit your question to include the revised query string (with the backticks) and all the error output.  Are you sure the error is for this query?  The syntax I included in my answer is valid.  I've tested it using sqlite3 and don't get an error.

Comment: Also, please note that the characters added around `replace` are backticks (ASCII code 96) **not** single quotes.  I think you entered single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I am too careless, the modified sql will run normally, the single quotes I used are wrong, your answer has been adopted.